# Using Google Developer API keys in distributed applications

Tags: api, api-key

I was looking at the Google Fonts Developer API, where you can programatically query the Google Fonts catalog and get some JSON results. You have to get a an API key through Google to use it.

I want to create an extension/plugin for a text editor where you can query the Google Fonts catalog using this API. I would plan on distributing this plugin for anyone to use.

However, in order for it work, I obviously have to sign up for an API key and include that in the code for the plugin so it gets distributed also.

I know that API keys like this as not secret passwords or anything like that, but should they be distributed like this? If one was to build something like this, this seems like the only way to do it.

What happens if someday my own Google account is compromised? What if I need to refresh the API key for some random reason, etc? Then all those users of the plugin would be out of luck since the plugin is using an old key.

What is the best approach to this type of problem? I was planning on having the API key to be "editable" in the plugin so that one could use their own key if they wished, but I don't want that to be a requirement because it just creates a higher barrier to entry.

Comment: You would want to have your own API with which this plugin communicates. It would act as a gateway to the Google APIs.